# qpython -(contact list command)

Tags: contacts, qpython

I wrote this command in editor qpython3 in my Android Handy.(Mi A3)
Why I get (name not define) this error?

MY CODE:

a = contactsGetIds()
print(a)

Error:

/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython3-android5.sh  /storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/.last_tmp.py  && exit
thon/scripts3/.last_tmp.py  && exit              <
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 1, in 
a = contactsGetIds()
NameError: name 'contactsGetIds' is not defined
1|:/ $

Comment: Where have you declared the function?